# Why isn't "Save" working correctly all of a sudden?

Tags: blend-files

I want to thank anyone in advance who responds.

I don't know if this is specific to the particular file, which I have never had any such problem with until the past day or so, but all of a sudden, when I open the file after saving and closing it, what is loaded differs from what I actually saved in that objects are missing and others are rotated and placed differently than I had them.

For example, I had full hinges and all the door knob and bolt pieces on the door off to the scene left side of the building, and the three door pieces were upright and were not overlapping my new front door when I saved the file, and even after I fixed it and saved, even exporting as an .obj file, it still comes up this way whenever I open the file.

[File in question](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3iO3keGWrXMd2dhekJneEFQUk0)

Comment: does it solve if you enter the firstframe with shift + left arrow?

Comment: Quite a few objects in that file have keyframes on them. If you move those objects and forget to key, they will for sure pop back to their old position. Most of the animated objects also don't change over time. Maybe you set keyframes on them by accident?

Comment: "does it solve if you enter the firstframe with shift + left arrow?" I'm sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean, but thank you very much for responding!

Comment: "Quite a few objects in that file have keyframes on them. If you move those objects and forget to key, they will for sure pop back to their old position. Most of the animated objects also don't change over time. Maybe you set keyframes on them by accident?" The duplicated hardware did have keyframes, and I didn't check whether or not the keyframes carried over to the duplicates, but I don't believe I played the animation. It seems likely that has something to do with it, and my mental clarity is currently not the best, so it is very much possible. Thank you very much for looking into this!!

Comment: The keyframes turned out to be the problem, and it is unbelievable to me that I didn't check that, as it seems to me the most obvious thing to look for. I have been experiencing such bizarre disruptions for years now in which I am unable to recognize the readily apparent and obvious in specific instances until I have made a fool of myself by making that absence of recognition known to someone. Then the thing ceases to be obscured and I am able to recognize it as usual. I am sorry that it caused anyone's time and effort to be wasted, and aliasguru and Faceb Faceb, thank you again very much!!